# Why am I getting 10 points for votes on my questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've noticed that my questions here get a rep of 10.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way things are on meta.

Prior to March 2010 up-votes on questions were worth 10 points across the Stack Exchange network. However, it was deemed that [a rebalancing was needed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) in favour of answers. However, due to the special nature of Meta it was decided to keep the old system here.

Answer (score 0):

Thus is was on all the sites for a long time, and so it continues to be on meta.

Comment: The grammar there throws me off-course. What do you mean it's on all sites. I haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @Tshepang: Obsolete grammatical constructs meant to sound mystic or some such nonsense. ChrisF's post is clear and has the link I was too lazy to find...