# Why don't I get 10 points for question upvotes on other metas?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting 10 points for votes on my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75991/why-am-i-getting-10-points-for-votes-on-my-questions)

A question upvote here gives user 10 rep, but on other metas it's 5. Why so?

[**update**]  [Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64267/is-there-a-reason-why-we-gain-ghost-reputation-on-the-meta-of-se-website), upvotes on per-site metas don't gain one any reputation. So misleading. All this time I thought...

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate is it?

Comment: You don't get *any* reputation for upvotes on other metas.

Comment: @balpha Huh? I certainly do (I just checked on askubuntu and unix.SE).

Comment: "Reputation is always inherited from the parent site. You cannot gain or lose reputation on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Comment: @balpha Please check.

Comment: You have 1765 on U&L, you have 1765 on meta.U&L. You have 342 on askubuntu, you have 342 on meta.askubuntu. Looks correct to me. Oh wait, maybe I get it -- are you talking about [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64267/is-there-a-reason-why-we-gain-ghost-reputation-on-the-meta-of-se-website)?

Comment: @balpha Ooohhh! Is that so! No wonder @Anna was so confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this meta is special.

Prior to the launch of the SE 2.0 sites (Web Applications etc.) there was only this meta site for Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User. With the expansion of sites it was decided that [each site would have it's own meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/). As part of this change it was decided that the meta would inherit the reputation from the parent site.

However, as this site was a fully fledged site with it's own reputation and because it's a place where questions about the whole network are asked it was decided that it would keep it's own separate reputation. To quote Jeff from the blog post I linked to:

> For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system. We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. **Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself** — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

Comment: More of a historical note than a rationale :)

Comment: @Tshepang - it's the reason. I'll add the relevant quote from the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

The second-last paragraph of ChrisF's answer is the rationale. :)

This site deals with the SE network in general so it's ill-fitting to have SO's rep carry over. Being an SO user with high rep doesn't make one qualified to comment on things for the English.SE site, for example.

At the same time, having high rep on English.SE very much means that the person is likely qualified to comment on the direction of English.SE, so their rep carries weight on English.SE meta.

In a way, you can think of StackOverflow meta as a separate StackExchange network site with its own rep.

Comment: You are addressing a different question.

Comment: @Tshepang How so? I answered why this meta give rep for upvotes and other metas don't.

Comment: Even that comment is wrong. Other metas do give rep on upvotes. Was it a typo?

Comment: Also, your answer fits the question "why is my rep from SO not carrying over to meta.SO?" and not "Why don't I get 10 points for question upvotes on other metas?"

Comment: @Tshepang If other metas give rep on upvotes, why are you asking here why you don't get rep? I'm very confused. I'm sorry you feel my answer isn't useful. I was trying to imply that you don't get rep for question upvotes on other sites because their rep is linked to their main sites, but that clearly didn't come across very well. My apologies.

Comment: I never said that other metas don't give rep for question upvotes. Where did you get that? And, no need for apologies. I guess it's a translation loss. You wanna read the (updated) question again? I've clarified.

Comment: @Tshepang Ahhhh. Okay, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks.